# How to add different Q.E.D. symbols to different theorems?

Tags: symbols, theorems

I have a series of theorem styles, two of them look like this:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{define}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

I want to add a `\blacksquare` to the end of each definition and a `\square` to every theorem (that is, in the last line aligned to the right).

I read about redefining the `\qedsymbol` to the desired value, but no theorem displays any symbol.
Then, I tried wrapping the theorem into an additional environment, but then LaTeX throws `missing $` errors at me. Both `\newenvironment` and `NewEnviron` produce these.

I would prefer to get the `theorem` system to add the symbol, anyway. So how can I specify the qed symbol to be used in your `\newtheorem`?

Comment: In `amsthm`, only proofs produce squares at the end. Theorem or Definition themselves _should not_ end with **Q.E.D.** symbol (since they we have not "**D.** emonstrated" anything in them). So I'm just making myself sure: you really want these symbols to appear at the end of **Theorems** and **Definitions** themselves?

Comment: @tohecz: Yes, but I did not invent this. I have always searched for a way to distinctively mark the end of a theorem or a definition to make clear where the theorem/definition ends and regular text continues. I saw this a couple times in literature and think a black square works well as full-stop-like indicator that now follows regular text. As far as I am concerned a Q.E.D. symbol is a hollow square (`\square`).

Comment: As long as you put your theorem in italics/slanted, you don't need any end-mark. But the truth is that I have seen it as well. On the other hand, I've seen a black square for the end of the proof too.

Comment: check out my answer to [qed-for-theorems-without-proofs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34014).  it has a link for an example document dealing with various situations other than simple proofs where an end-of-whatever marker is wanted, compatible with `amsthm`.  actually, this question might be considered a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I sometimes put a tombstone at the end of examples or at the end of corollaries for which no laid out proof is given. But there is no need to mark the end of *all* theorems or definitions (definitions are just running text, most of the time, simply set with more evidence): the mark at the end of a statement should have a *special* meaning, such as the absence of a proof because it's obvious or follows easily from the preceding statement. In my opinion, *different* tombstones for different environments are definitely out of the question.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily achieve what you want using [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) as a front-end for `amsthm`; a little example:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=definition,name=Definition,qed=$\blacksquare$]{define}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,qed=$\square$]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{define}
Test definition.
\end{define}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm still unable to get this to work. I downloaded the newest `thmtools` package as my version didn't have `declaretheoremstyle` (which you have to use for `qed` to work`) but whenever I use that I get an `Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \NR@gettitle` which tells me absolutely nothing. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @bitmask without some code is hard to tell what's going on. Please compose a minimal working example illustrating the problem and upload it elsewhere (pastebin, for example), and then provide the link here so I can take a look at the code.

Comment: I am talking about the general use of the package. For example with exactly the code as you provide it (just with the `qed` parameter passed to `delcaretheoremstyle` instead of `declaretheorem` as per documentation [the latter doesn't have the `qed` parameter]). I understand that it works for you, but I am unable to determine what the error could mean. Maybe it's my not so up-to-date latex sources plus the newest version of `thmtools`. Actually, I don't even have to declar any theorem whatsoever, I just have to include the package.

Comment: @bitmask so `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=definition,name=Definition,qed=$\blacksquare$]{define}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,qed=$\square$]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{define}
Test definition.
\end{define}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}` *exactly* as it is gives you errors? If so, could you please tell me exactly the first error obtained?