# Mark end of Theorem

Tags: fonts, theorems

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97128/5001) Palatino text font is used together with the AMS Euler (eulervm) math font. The following statement is reasonable:

> Note also that because the "Euler" fonts have an upright rather than slanted appearance, the text part of the Residue Theorem's statement is set in upright letters rather than in italics.

If the Theorem's statement is set in upright letters, what is the best/correct way to mark the end of the Theorem and the beginning of "normal" text?

Comment: Well ypou can add an end-mark for any theorem-like structure, which can be whatever you please and be different for say, theorems an proofs – at least with `ntheorem`, which is the package I know best. Also, these theorem structures have a special vertical spacing built-in, which you may increase.

Comment: take a look at [\qed for theorems without proofs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34021/579).  it links indirectly to a document that addresses adding end-marks in a number of non-proof situations.