# QED symbol after statements without proof

Tags: amsthm, newtheorem

I use the `amsbook` document class and I would like to show `\qed` symbols at the end of statements without proofs (using the theorem environment, such as `theorem`, `proposition`, `lemma`, ...) to indicate that these are known but I do not present a proof.

Is there a simple (or even predefined way) of doing so, such as using

```
\begin{mytheorem}{\qed}
...
\end{mytheorem}
```

for any theorem environment `mytheorem` without doing

```
\newtheorem{mytheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{mytheoremqed}[theorem]{Theorem}
\AtEndEnvironment{mytheoremqed}{\null\hfill\qedsymbol}
... % repeat for proposition, lemma, corollary, ...
```

for every theorem environment I have (this solution was described in [\qed for theorems without proofs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34014)) ?

Preferrably, also  both versions

```
\begin{mytheorem}[{\cite{myref}}]
```

and

```
\begin{mytheorem}{\qed}[{\cite{myref}}]
```

should work.

Comment: Why not the simpler solution by Marco Daniel? That is, adding `\qed` at the end of the statement. It is the *only* good answer to the question you link to.

Comment: Because I prefer to handle situations uniformly instead of taking care of them individually. First, I could remove them all simultaneously when I (or the journal) decide to do so (okay, I could do so as well using a ``\myqed``). Second, I could properly adjust where to show them. Third, I can much easier search for those statements I have which I do not prove.

Comment: Well, it's not a big deal, and I guess I could also do this individually as you suggest.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you'd like to have `\begin{mytheorem}{}` for theorems with a proof and `\begin{mytheorem}{\qed}` for those without one?

Comment: I'd prefer to use the to-often-used-to-change ``\begin{mytheorem}`` and a new ``\begin{mytheorem}{\qed}``. Added additional preferred property to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let me show an example where `\null\hfill\qedsymbol` doesn't do the right thing. Note that adding `\null\hfill\qedsymbol` explicitly is the same as doing it with `\AtEndEnvironment`, with the only difference that the indirect method does not take care of a possible space before `\null`, making things worse.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some long theorem statement,
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long
enough to show bad effect.\null\hfill\qedsymbol
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have several better choices for this. The simpler, in my opinion, is to append `\qed` at the end of statements you don't give a proof of.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some long theorem statement,
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long
enough to show bad effect.\qed
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Same text as before, but the tombstone ends up where desired.

[image]

A different approach would be to define a different environment, say a `*`-variant:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem*}
 {\pushQED{\qed}\theorem}
 {\popQED\endtheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem*}
Some long theorem statement,
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem*}

\end{document}
```

This has the disadvantage of requiring the `*` in both the `\begin` and `\end` part, but has some advantages: you don't need to change the input in case you decide for suppressing those tombstones; you can easily change the tombstone for these cases.

A third possibility could be defining `theorem` as an environment with a mandatory argument, like

```
\begin{theorem}{}
...<statement>...
\end{theorem}
```

when you don't want a tombstone and

```
\begin{theorem}{\qed}
...<statement>...
\end{theorem}
```

It could be arranged so as to support

```
\begin{theorem}
...<statement>...
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed
...<statement>...
\end{theorem}
```

with the following trick:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newif\ifstumpqed

\newtheorem{theoremInner}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1]
 {\ifx#1\qed\stumpqedtrue\pushQED{\qed}\fi\theoremInner}
 {\ifstumpqed\popQED\fi\endtheoremInner}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed\label{whatever}
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed[Whatever]\label{foo}
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

If you have several of these declarations to manage, you can abstract the procedure:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\addqed}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1Inner\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1Inner\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
    \ifx##1\qed\stumpqedtrue\pushQED{\qed}\fi\csname #1Inner\endcsname
  }%
  \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{%
    \ifstumpqed\popQED\fi\csname end#1Inner\endcsname
  }%
}
\newif\ifstumpqed

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\addqed{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed\label{whatever}
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\qed[Whatever]\label{foo}
Some long theorem statement, 
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long long
long long long long 
enough to show bad effect.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

So, after a `\newtheorem` declaration with the usual methods, add

```
\addqed{<env name>}
```

and you're done.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort, and for presenting a negative example for ``\null\hfill\qedsymbol``! I like the star version the most. But what I do not like about it, though, is that I have to repeat the same lines for for every environment  (e.g., ``proposition`` and ``proposition*``, ``lemma`` and ``lemma*``, and so on). Do you see any way to avoid this code duplication?

Comment: @ChristianStump I added an “abstraction layer”.

Comment: Great, I will start playing with it -- thanks again!